# How to show angular array items on HTML

Tags: html, angular, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to show the value of ing1 of item1 on html
[image: I want to show the value of ing1 of item1 on html]

item2 works but item1.ing1 does note work
[image: item2 works but item1.ing1 does note work]

how can I show ing1 value on html file. Thanks

Comment: click and see the picture thanks

Comment: Please always post read `code block` **not image** at your question to let others reproduce your problem quickly.

Comment: product.item1[0].ing1  , item1 is an array

Comment: @YunxiZhao Is `item1` always having only one element, or can there be more than one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to select the number in the array `{{product.item1[0].ing1 }}`

Answer (score 0):

item1 is an array of objects. To display the ing1 value (considering it always comes at 0th index), you can write as follow:

```
product.item1[0].ing1
```

I also assume that you are doing `ng-repeat` on `gems` and its each item is `product`